# url rewriting and redirection using .htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

I have been trying to rewrite dynamically generated URLs to static URLs. For example I achieve this URL after implementation of `.htaccess` command:

Rewritten URL: http://www.risenotes.com/top/Love-best-quotes

while actual URL is: http://www.risenotes.com/quotes/great-best-quotations.php?topic=Love

I am using below command for this purpose:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^top/([^/]*)-best-quotes$ /quotes/great-best-quotations.php?topic=$1 [L]
```

My code works perfectly well for above but I want to redirect all requests for

```
/quotes/great-best-quotations.php?topic=Love
```

to newly rewritten URL

```
/top/Love-best-quotes.
```

Can anyone guide me please???